# Get the actual angle postRotate

Tags: android

Maybe i'm asking something evident, but i can't find a solution, so i have a imageview wich is a crossbow and i want it to shot to where i touch on the screen, i use postRotate to rotate it in function of where you touch, the problem is that each time that you touch it adds the new angle to the old one and so on. There is a way to get the actual angle of the ImageView?

```
    int scrWidth  = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int scrHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        float x=event.getX();//capturamos x e y
        float y=event.getY();
        float i=0;


        if(y<(scrHeight/2)){
            float yf=(scrHeight/2)-y;//obtenemos la y respecto a la mitad de la pantalla 
            double alfa=Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yf, x));//encontramos el angulo para las x e y encontradas
            float beta= (float) alfa; //convertimos a float para rotar
            beta=beta+i;                
            matrix.postRotate(-beta, ballesta.getWidth()/2,ballesta.getHeight()/2); //primer valor angulo, segundo y tercero punto de ancla de la imagen
            ballesta.setImageMatrix(matrix);                
        }
        if(y>(scrHeight/2)){
            float yf=y-(scrHeight/2);//obtenemos la y respecto a la mitad de la pantalla
            double alfa=Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yf, x));//encontramos el angulo para las x e y encontradas
            float beta= (float) alfa; //convertimos a float para rotar
            beta=beta+i;
            matrix.postRotate(beta, ballesta.getWidth()/2,ballesta.getHeight()/2);
            ballesta.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i allready found the solution, plus i missed info in my question (all the code is inside of a ontouch event). 
The solution was to declare a static variable outside of the ontouch event, and then i keep the angle that i rotate each time in that variable, and in the begining of the event i rotate minus the static variable. Not sure if i was very clear (i'm quite sleepy :P).